# Why is calling this method giving error "Unbound method ... instance as first arg"?

Tags: python, class, methods, instance, typeerror

```
class stack:
    def __init__(self):
        self.st = []
    def push(self, x):
        self.st.append(x)
        return self
    def pop(self):
        return self.st.pop()
```

Can someone tell me why I can't run python and do stack.push(3) without getting the unbound error.  I do the following

```
>>> from balance import *
>>> stack.push(3)
Traceback (most recent call last):File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unbound method push() must be called with stack instance as first argument (got int instance instead)
>>>
```

But when I write this code I can push to the stack without error:

```
import sys

k = sys.argv[1]

class stack:
    def __init__(self):
        self.st = []
    def push(self, x):
        self.st.append(x)
        return self
    def pop(self):
        return self.st.pop()
    def isEmpty(self):   #added an empty fucntion to stack class
        return self.st == []

def balance(k):
    braces = [ ('(',')'), ('[',']'), ('{','}') ] #list of braces to loop through
    st = stack() #stack variable

    for i in k:   #as it iterates through input 
              #it checks against the braces list
        for match in braces:
            if i == match[0]:  #if left brace put in stack
                st.push(i)
            elif i == match[1] and st.isEmpty():  #if right brace with no left
                st.push(i)                        #append for condition stateme$
            elif i == match[1] and not st.isEmpty() and st.pop() != match[0]:
                st.push(i)   #if there are items in stack pop
                         # for matches and push rest to stack

if st.isEmpty(): #if empty stack then there are even braces
    print("Yes")
if not st.isEmpty():  #if items in stack it is unbalanced
    print("No")


balance(k) #run balance function
```

Comment: Always name a **class** with MixedCase, and an **instance** with lowercase, as idjaw and PEP-8 say. Then you can't confuse a class with an instance, as you're doing here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error is telling you the exact problem:

```
...method push() must be called with stack instance...
```

You are doing this:

```
stack.push(3)
```

Which is *not* a stack instance. You are trying to call an instance method as a class method, because you haven't instantiated `stack`. For example:

```
>>> st = stack()
>>> st.push(3)
```

You actually did this properly in your balance function:

```
st = stack() #stack variable
```

Now you actually have an instance of `stack`. You also *clearly* use it properly further down in your code here, for example:

```
st.push(i)
```

Furthermore, you should not be calling `stack` a variable, it is a *class*.

You should also reference the [PEP8 style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) to adhere to proper conventions. For example, classes should be uppercase: `stack` should be `Stack`

Comment: Thank you. Our professor never told us creating a variable for a class or function was instantiating anything. Thoughyt it was

Comment: Thought it was a thing people did. Thank you for clarifying it all.